# How can I access and mutate objects stored in a vector C++

Tags: c++, object, vector

So I'm working on a project that sorts drivers by distance and time. Currently I have an overloaded constructor creating a new object based off an input and the storing them into a vector. I'm also then calling on a setName() function for a string in the class with the name of the driver.

Later, I need to recognize a trip command and then pull the object from the vector. The code I'm using to do that is below.

```
for (vector<Driver>::iterator i = drivers.begin(); i != drivers.end(); i++) {
                Driver tempObj = *i;
                string temp = tempObj.getName();
                cout << temp << endl;
            }
```

Below is my code for setName() and getName()

```
string Driver::getName() { return driverName; }
void Driver::setDriverName(string n) {n = driverName;}
```

And my current output is giving me empty lines as an ouput. Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like the issue probably lies with your method `getName()`. Perhaps you should attach the code for that as well

Comment: Not sure how this code works: `void Driver::setDriverName(string n) {n = driverName;}` . Seems like you are seeting the argument equal to the current driverName.  Did you want `void Driver::setDriverName(string n) {driverName = n;}` ?

Comment: Please do provide a [mcve]. Do you actually push anything into the vector?

Comment: I see that you removed quite a bit of your code.  When @user463035818 asked for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I believe he meant something that we could paste into our  compiler and play with.  A minimal example would have to show us the Driver object in such a way that we can see what is happening with the assignments and which we can compile.  It takes work to create a minimal example, but you usually solve your problem as you go through that effort.  Otherwise, you make it easier for others to help.

Comment: rearranging my set function worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your driverName set function as follows:

```
void Driver::setDriverName(string n) {driverName = n;}
```

Note that you cannot assign a value to the argument of a function and hope to understand what is happening unless it is passed in by reference :-).

Answer (score 0):

You **copy** a `Driver` when you `Driver tempObj = *i;`, there is no further association between those objects. In the code not shown where you populate `drivers`, you are likely doing similar.

Your `setDriverName` has no effect, all it does is modify a **copy** of a string that immediately ceases to exist.

```
void Driver::setDriverName(string n) {n = driverName;}
```

Rather than copy your `Driver`s, you can reference them.

```
for (auto & driver : drivers) {
    string name = driver.getName();
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    driver.setName("New Name");
}
```

Comment: i was about to write a similar answer, though it turned out that the question/problem was due to something completely unrelated to accessing the objects in the vector :\